# Ratios containing zero

Tags: ratio

In one of our questions in school, we are asked,

> For a given index finger length which of the following groups has the longest ring finger if the $2$D:$4$D ratio is:
>
> Group A $0.96$,
>
> Group B $0.98 $
>
> Group C $0.99$ and
>
> Group D $1.01$.

[Definition: $2$D:$4$D ratio means the ratio of the length of the index finger(2D) to ring finger (4D)]

The answer is Group A but I'm finding it very difficult to understand this especially with zeros involved in the ratios. 
I would be very grateful if someone could explain where the answer came from and how you got it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is easier for you if you consider the 4D:2D ratio, which is always the reciprocal of the 2D:4D, for example for group A it is $\frac1{0.96}\approx 1.04$ and so no longer has that pesky zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $2D:4D$ ratio essentially represents $\frac{2D}{4D}$ , where $2D$ is the length of the index finger , and $4D$ is the length of the ring finger .

We are given that $2D$ is constant . Therefore , we have :-

**For group A**:- $\frac{2D}{4D} =0.96 \implies 4D = \frac{2D}{0.96}$

**For group B**:- $4D=\frac{2D}{0.98}$

**For group C**:- $4D=\frac{2D}{0.99}$

**For group D**:- $4D=\frac{2D}{1.01}$

Now recall that for a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ , the greater the denominator $b$ , the smaller the fraction . The denominator is least in case of group A , and hence $4D$ is greatest , for group A.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot